# Radius of convergence of the taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2}$ about $z=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2}$

I need to determine the radius of convergence of the taylor series of $f$ about $z=0$.

**My 1st approach**

If I can write $f$ as a power series, then it will be equal to the taylor series about 0, and thus I can determine the radius by using the cauchy-hadamard theorem. However, I haven't been able to write $f$ as a power series.

**My 2nd approach**

Using the cauchy integral formula, I can determine the taylor series directly:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n =
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial K(0,r)}
\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz \cdot z^n
$$

where $\partial K(0,r)$ is some appropriate circle with center 0. However, this seems to be difficult to evaluate...

**My 3rd approach**

We can write $f$ as a product of two series:

$$
f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+2}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{z^2}{2})} e^{iz}
    =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^n
     \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(iz)^{n}}{n!}
$$

and since the 2nd infinite series has infinite radius of convergence, we only need to determine the radius of convergence of the first geometric series. However, I don't know how this is related to the taylor series of $f$...

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If i remember correctly, then the power series of a holomorphic function converges on the largest disc contained in the domain. Now the function is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ i\sqrt{2}, -i\sqrt{2} \}$, so it will converge on a disc with radius $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: If an analytic function has the first singularity (in absolute value) at $|z_0|=R$ then the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at $0$ is precisely $R$ so here this gives $\sqrt 2$ as the answer. To prove the above use cauchy  estimates for the Taylor series coefficients on any smaller disc $r <R$ to show the Taylor series has radius at least $r$ and then conclude since the radius clearly cannot be bigger than $R$

Comment: Of course, I should have seen that. The einstellung effect, I guess...

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power series of a holomorphic function converges on the largest disc contained in the domain. Now the function is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{i\sqrt{2},−i\sqrt{2}\}$, so it will converge on a disc with radius $\sqrt{2}$.

To check that it does not converge on a larger disc, we must check that $i\sqrt{2}$ and $−i\sqrt{2}$ are not removable singularities, which they are not.

Comment: As a remark: Your third approach should also give you this result. The product of two power series are related through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product .